# How do I enable RBAC access for a group to view Function App "Log Stream" in Azure?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

How do I enable RBAC access for a group to view Function App "Log Stream" in Azure?

Basically, I have a AD group with an assignee ID.  I don't know how to find the "scope id" for the "Log Stream".   My users have contributor access to the Function App itself, but the "Log Stream" is not permitted.

I configured Terraform like so,  to enable "Application Insights Contributor" scope for my users but they still cannot see the "Log Stream".  So, I am just trying to identify which of the RBAC roles encompasses the "Log Stream" viewing.  Does anyone know?

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "azurerm_ai_contributor" {
  count                = var.environment != "prod" ? 1 : 0
  principal_id         = local.dev_team_object_id
  role_definition_name = "Application Insights Component Contributor"
  scope                = azurerm_application_insights.i.id
}
```

I'm guessing: is there a way to give "Reader" permission to all of "Monitoring" within my function app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide [Log Analytics Reader role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#log-analytics-reader) to the desired group scoped to the function app.